# App keeps shutting down due to java.Lang.RuntimeException

Tags: java, android, service

I wrote a simple practice app in the background to generate random numbers constantly using Started Services when a button is pressed.

Unfortunately, the app keeps shutting down with the **java.Lang.RuntimeException** with the message **Unable to start service**. Could anyone tell me why this happens?

**MyService.class**

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.util.Random;

public class MyService extends Service {

    Random randomGenerator;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        randomGenerator = new Random();
        Toast.makeText(this, randomGenerator.nextInt(1000), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.class**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView timerTextView;
    private Button startButton;
    private Button stopButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        timerTextView = findViewById(R.id.timerTextView);
        startButton = findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        stopButton = findViewById(R.id.stopButton);

        startButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        stopButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v == startButton)
            startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));

        if (v == stopButton)
            stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timerTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="225dp"
        android:text="@string/timerString"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/timerTextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="@string/startButton"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stopButton"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/startButton"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:text="@string/stopButton"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**The Stacktrace**

```
2020-04-19 20:20:48.147 8493-8493/com.example.servicespractice W/System.err: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x2d2
2020-04-19 20:20:48.147 8493-8493/com.example.servicespractice W/System.err:     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:360)
2020-04-19 20:20:48.147 8493-8493/com.example.servicespractice W/System.err:     at android.content.res.MiuiResources.getText(MiuiResources.java:97)
2020-04-19 20:20:48.147 8493-8493/com.example.servicespractice W/System.err:     at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:309)
2020-04-19 20:20:48.147 8493-8493/com.example.servicespractice W/System.err:     at com.example.servicespractice.MyService.onStartCommand(MyService.java:26)
2020-04-19 20:20:48.147 8493-8493/com.example.servicespractice W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3700)
2020-04-19 20:20:48.148 8493-8493/com.example.servicespractice W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:200)
2020-04-19 20:20:48.148 8493-8493/com.example.servicespractice W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1704)
2020-04-19 20:20:48.148 8493-8493/com.example.servicespractice W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
2020-04-19 20:20:48.148 8493-8493/com.example.servicespractice W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
2020-04-19 20:20:48.148 8493-8493/com.example.servicespractice W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6823)
2020-04-19 20:20:48.148 8493-8493/com.example.servicespractice W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2020-04-19 20:20:48.148 8493-8493/com.example.servicespractice W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
2020-04-19 20:20:48.148 8493-8493/com.example.servicespractice W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
2020-04-19 20:20:53.379 8493-8493/com.example.servicespractice E/ervicespractic: Invalid ID 0x00000200.
2020-04-19 20:20:53.380 8493-8493/com.example.servicespractice W/System.err: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x200
2020-04-19 20:20:53.380 8493-8493/com.example.servicespractice W/System.err:     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:360)
2020-04-19 20:20:53.380 8493-8493/com.example.servicespractice W/System.err:     at android.content.res.MiuiResources.getText(MiuiResources.java:97)
2020-04-19 20:20:53.380 8493-8493/com.example.servicespractice W/System.err:     at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:309)
2020-04-19 20:20:53.380 8493-8493/com.example.servicespractice W/System.err:     at com.example.servicespractice.MyService.onStartCommand(MyService.java:26)
2020-04-19 20:20:53.380 8493-8493/com.example.servicespractice W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3700)
2020-04-19 20:20:53.380 8493-8493/com.example.servicespractice W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:200)
2020-04-19 20:20:53.380 8493-8493/com.example.servicespractice W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1704)
2020-04-19 20:20:53.381 8493-8493/com.example.servicespractice W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
2020-04-19 20:20:53.381 8493-8493/com.example.servicespractice W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
2020-04-19 20:20:53.381 8493-8493/com.example.servicespractice W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6823)
2020-04-19 20:20:53.381 8493-8493/com.example.servicespractice W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2020-04-19 20:20:53.381 8493-8493/com.example.servicespractice W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
2020-04-19 20:20:53.381 8493-8493/com.example.servicespractice W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
2020-04-19 20:20:53.511 8493-8541/com.example.servicespractice I/ervicespractic: ProcessProfilingInfo new_methods=1031 is saved saved_to_disk=1 resolve_classes_delay=8000
```

Comment: Can you please show the full stack trace?

Comment: I don't know how to do that. I've shared the Logcat information if that is what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
Toast.makeText(this, randomGenerator.nextInt(1000), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

with :

```
Toast.makeText(this,Integer.toString(randomGenerator.nextInt(1000)), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Holy shit, can't believe it was that simple. Tell me, if you would, so I want the app to constantly keep popping these random numbers. However, the app stops at one. Could you tell me how?

Comment: Because onStartCommand() is called once when Service is started. If you want to keep popping these random numbers, you need to start Background Thread or Timer inside Service and display toast from there.

Comment: I have done similar with my timer demo app which updated timer time in notification. You can refer to the following code : https://github.com/saurabh1489/TimerAppDemo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/sample/servicedemo/service/TimerService.kt